# Нрав и норов

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Как я понимаю, это, в принципе, одно и то же слово. Но почему-то при этом первый вариант означает просто характер, а второй — строптивый характер.
Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово «нрав» в современном языке  имеет два значения: а) Характер. Крутой нрав. Добрый нрав. б) Обычай, уклад. Старинные нравы.

Слово «норов» раньше имело те же значения, но затем пути этих слов разошлись.  В настоящий момент «норов» имеет следующие значения:  А) Нрав, обычай (стар.). Что город, то норов. Б) Упрямство,  характер  с причудами  (прост.): Человек  с норовом. Укроти свой норов!

Интересно происхождение этих слов (др.рус. норовъ и ст.-сл нрав).  Они относятся к общеславянской лексике, а в их основе лежит значение «желать, хотеть, проявлять силу, способность к сопротивлению».

В 15 веке отмечается слово «норовити» – делать послабление, угождать кому-либо. И современное слово «нравиться»  относится к предметам, которые угождают нашему вкусу, располагают к себе.

Answer (score 2):

Норовить-настойчиво стремиться к чему-либо,добиться чего-либо(идет как отрицательное значение) Норовит все сделать по-своему...
В этом их различия.